# Am I @localhost or @computer-5?

Tags: hostname

Why is bash shell sometimes saying I'm at `@localhost` while other times it says I'm at `@computer-5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some DHCP servers (and clients) are configured to assign a hostname just like an IP address.  In these cases the computer's hostname does in fact change to e. g. `computer-5` (until it gets a lease assigning a different name, or the lease is relinquished).  `localhost` will still work for the loopback interface, but the DHCP-assigned hostname will (or should) resolve to the DHCP-assigned address specifically.